# Complext "button" (LinearLayout with child views) with background drawable - on children click doesn't reflect the "state_pressed"

Tags: android, childviews

I have a LinearLayout that has 2 children: a ImageView aligned left and a TextView aligned right.

I've set the background of the LinearLayout to be a @drawable XML resource that has two `<item>` tags. One of them has `android:state_pressed="true"`. Also, the LinearLayout has `android:clickable="true"`.

When the LinearLayout is clicked it correctly changes its background to the `android:state_pressed` style, but clicking on one of its children doesn't propagate the click action up to the LinearLayout.

Is there a way to easily achieve a click state on the parent view when a child view is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if it works for your specific implementation, but a very easy way of achieving this "complex" button is by making a normal button and using `android:drawableLeft` or `android:drawableRight` or `android:drawableTop` or `android:drawableBottom` and `android:drawablePaddig` to achieve the same visual result in just one view.

for example:

```
<LinearLayout orientation=vertical>
    <ImageView/>
    <TextView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

is pretty much the same as

```
<Button
   drawableLeft="@drawable/..."
   text="..."
/>
```

that way your whole layout is simpler and the pressed states works out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2):

**Dont use Both as it will give Exception**

Use this to your parent

```
android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
```

Or add in your child views

```
`android:duplicateParentState="true"`
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a single `TextView` and using the `android:drawableLeft` or `android:drawableRight` attribute to show your image. It's better design and more performant than a `LinearLayout` with two children.

If that won't work for you, try adding `android:addStatesFromChildren="true"` to the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: very sorry I answered the same thing. My mistake, didn't read the whole page.